# Appending to a URL in JQuery and HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, mongodb

I am trying to add a word to the end of a URL which i receive from my MongoDB.I am using window.location to get the current url and am trying to append the phrase data[i].url from the database.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#test").click(function(){
    var x = window.location = "www.rand.com/";;
    var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    if(result.length>0) {
        var resultString = "";
        result.each(function () {
            resultString += $(this).val() + " ";
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/recipe',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({"search": resultString}),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    $("#dataId").append("<ul>" + data[i].name + "</ul>" + "<button onclick='" + x + data[id].url + "'</button>");
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        alert("No checkbox checked");
    }
});
```

});

The connection to the database is working as i have this already this tested, I am just trying to create a HTML button which when clicked will append the phrase received to the end of the URL. (Also data.name and the button prints out but button functionality doesnt work)

Comment: Append how?  As apart of a query string?  As part of the path?

Comment: Append to the end of the URL so yes the path

Comment: First off I feel like this is an issue.  `var x = window.location = "www.rand.com/";;`  As soon as you change that window.location there, it's going to try to do a page transition.  Are you seeing a page transition when test is clicked?

Comment: @Taplar When i click the button made in HTML, it basically reloads the page

Comment: Ok, right.  Because of the page transition I mentioned.  You don't want to change the `window.location` until it needs to be changed, because that will cause the page to transition away from the page you are currently on.

Comment: @Taplar Ok so shlould i include 'window.location' in the '.append()' ?

Comment: You could try `'<button onclick="window.location = \''+ data[id].url+'\'" ...` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a string of the URL you want to create then you could use the following

```
var url = window.location.href + "/" + data[i].url;
```

That would display something similar to http://www.webaddress.com/whatever-is-in-data